# TreeView value for Node

Tags: c#, telerik, treeview

Im using this code for create a node:

```
private void radButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.radTreeView1.Nodes.Add(new RadTreeNode("Personal Folders"));
            this.radTreeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(new RadTreeNode("Simpson"));
            this.radTreeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(new RadTreeNode("Maggy")); 
            this.radTreeView1.Nodes.Add(new RadTreeNode("Friends"));
            this.radTreeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add(new RadTreeNode("Pig"));
            radTreeView1.ExpandAll();
        }
private void radTreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, RadTreeViewEventArgs e)
        {           
            MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text);
        }
```

And the result is perfect:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRuU3.png

But i need to set a value every node es: if i click on Maggy return 12121

All content will be dynamic with the while.

I'm really in trouble, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a value while adding the RadTreeNode, in this way you can retrieve the value of a RadTreeNode too.

```
    RadTreeNode newNode = new RadTreeNode();
    newNode.Text = "Maggy";
    newNode.Value = "12121";
```